# What is the in-universe significance of different colours of lightsabers in Star Wars?

Tags: analysis, star-wars

In the Star Wars universe Jedi use different colours of lightsabers. I have noticed blue, green and purple in Star Wars original and prequel trilogy (I heard there are more lightsaber colours too). And Sith use the red lightsabers. I do know why [Sith lightsabers' are red](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/in-the-star-wars-franchise-what-causes-the-sith-to-always-have-red-light-sabres/27810#27810). But why are Jedi's lightsabers of different colour and what significance or importance do they have? I heard some story about their out of universe reason but I am seeking for in-universe reason.

Comment: Related question on SFF:SE - [What is the reason that lightsabers have different colors?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1779/23386)

Comment: Purple was not in the Original trilogy. Samuel L Jackson had the fact that he would have the only purple lightsaber (cant remember if it was just for AofC or if it was for the movie universe) written into his contract. He chose purple because it is his favorite color, it had not been used until that point in a Star Wars movie, and having a unique lightsaber color would make it easier to identify himself in the Arena scene. For all colors and meanings http://origamiyoda.com/submission/star-wars-all-lightsaber-colors-and-meanings/

Comment: @user2989297 What is the source for the info on that page?!  It claims that Mace Windu used to be a Sith, I've never heard that.

Comment: @Andrew no idea, it was a quick google. I used to obsess over another website that was much better, like a lightsaber specific wookiepedia, but I wasnt able to re-find it 10 years later. Back then, my knowledge was that Mace Windu was the creator of Vaapad (probably just a user by the time clone wars hit), a dark side variety lightsaber stance. His apprentice fell to the dark side because he taught her Vaapad. Im trying to remember. I dont remember any indication that he was a Sith in that book. Just that he regularly channeled the dark side, and often struggled with it.

Comment: @Andrew Actually no. In Shatterpoint, I think I remember him talking about Jedi recruiting him off his homeworld as a child, and in his lifetime, Palpatine, Plageous, and Vader were the only Sith, so the idea that Mace worked with one of them is... impossible. If that was said on that website, I wouldnt trust the website to be current or former canon.

Comment: @user2989297 Yeah it says "Purple = Used by people who were siths for a short time then became jedi Users: Mace Windu, Mara Jade Skywalker, Jana Solo, The Dark Woman, Kit Darren, and Jaden Kor".  Probably not trustworthy.  The story I heard about Mace Windu's purple saber is simply that Samuel L. Jackson wanted to stand out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## UPDATE: Disney canon:

As per "Ashoka" novel by E.K. Johnston (via [ScreenRant](http://screenrant.com/secrets-trivia-revealed-about-ahsoka-tano-in-new-star-wars-novel/)), Sith red color is explained. No more synthetic crystals.

> Kyber crystals choose Force users and present themselves to their desired owner, but dark siders don’t experience this same connection to the cystals. **The only way the Sith and other dark side Force users can collect kyber crystals is by stealing them or plundering them off the bodies of their fallen foes. Even if a dark sider were to acquire a kyber crystal from a green or blue saber, the act of bending the crystal to their will in a new lightsaber will cause the crystal to “bleed,” turning it red**.

---

## Pre-Disney canon

First, some in-universe background (some of which you may know if you know "why red").

- At the heart of every lightsaber there is a "[Kyber Crystal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal)"

  > The crystals concentrated energy in a unique manner and were attuned to the Force, resonating with it
- In Star Wars universe, Kyber Crystals come in 2 distinct varieties: naturally harvested (of varying colors) and synthesized using the help from  the Force (when Dark Side is used, it imbues them with red(dish) color, as your linked answer hopefully states).
- For natural crystals, which color crystal you used depended on the era:

  - Old Republic era - ~4000 BBY (Before Battle of Yavin). No films/TV shows depict it:

    > Around 4000 BBY, lightsaber crystals were used to indicate a Jedi's chosen class. Blue indicated a Jedi Guardian, a Jedi who used the Force on a more physical level. Green indicated a Jedi Consular, a Jedi who preferred to reflect on the mysteries of the Force and fight the dark side at its heart. Yellow indicated a Jedi Sentinel, a Jedi who honed their skills in a balance of combat and scholarly pursuits. (source: [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal))
  - In later years (around Star Wars movies times) that has long stopped, and the colors were simply a Jedi's personal preference, or which crystal they managed to get; especially post-Empire-creation time when they became a great rarity.

Comment: Which canon does this information fall under?